# Как присвоить переменной класса результат выражения?

Tags: php

Вот так код работает:

```
<?php 
$a = 1;
$b = "$a";
```

Вот такой вызов выдаёт ошибку:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
class CL {
   var $b = "$a";
}
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Не понимаю, почему вдруг конструкция прерывает строку так, что вторые кавычки теряют силу? Как вызвать $a, не выходя за пределы строки и не меняя структуру класса?

---

Я всё понял. Только ошибка о том, что не закрыта кавычка. А не о том, что это какая-то запретная в синтаксисе конструкция создания класса.

Можно вообще хоть какой-то вызов сделать в моей задаче без конструктора? Пусть он даже вообще ничего не делает и возвращает пустое место, но не ругается на кавычку?

Возможна конструкция

```
class CL{
   public $a = "123";
   public $b = "{какой-то вызов}"
}
```

Кровь из носа надо вызов организовать без каких-либо конструкторов.
Работал пару лет с питоном. Там вообще проблем никаких. Всё ясно, понятно и гибко.

Comment: Не знаю как в php, но обычно в ООП вот так при объявлении класса задать дефолтное значение можно только статическому члену класса. Ибо значения обычных свойств класса свои у каждого экземпляра. Все требуемые значения должна присваивать функция-констрактор

Comment: @Mike тем не менне, вот так работает https://eval.in/501948 А переменную не ест

Comment: вот так `var $b = '$a';` можно. А Ваш вариант плох. Когда создается класс, значение переменной $a может быть неизвестно.

Comment: У вас в двойных ковычках находится переменная, которая неопределена в классе.. Отсюда и ошибка. А вне класса `$a=1` никак не влияет ни на что, она не является внутренней переменной класса и никак с ней не связана

Comment: Парсер кода не настолько "умный", чтобы полностью анализировать код и давать подробное описание каждого из типа ошибок. Настолько продвинутого ИИ еще нет. Причину ошибки я обозначил максимально точно. Ответ на ваше дополнение: нет, нельзя. Я четко обозначил, что в значениях по умолчанию можно указывать только скалярные значения, а не выражения. В чем проблема использования конструктора? Он вызовется автоматически при создании класса и сделает ровно то, что вам нужно. В дальнейшем редактируйте вопрос, а не добавляйте ответы, если вам есть, что добавить. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Павлов Денис impossibru. Поймите интерпретатор ругается не на ковычки, а на то,что он не может распознать откуда у него непонятно что в этих ковычках взялось

Comment: @Павлов Денис  написал вариант с константой..... но это при условии если вы не захотите `a` изменять и она особо не нужна....

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, вы используете устаревший синтаксис.

> **Замечание:** Метод объявления переменной через ключевое слово `var`, принятый в PHP 4, до сих пор поддерживается в целях совместимости (как
>   синоним ключевого слова `public`). В версиях PHP 5 ниже 5.1.3 такое
>   использование выводит предупреждение **E_STRICT**.

Подробнее в [документации](http://php.net/public)

Во-вторых, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной в качестве значения по умолчанию результат выполнения **выражения**. Это недопустимо. Таким образом можно присваивать только **скалярные значения**.

Почему `"$a"` выражение? Потому что здесь происходит неявное преобразование переменной в строку.

Ваш код следует преобразовать таким образом, чтобы выражение присваивалось переменной или в конструкторе, или в функции-сеттере.

Например, так:

```
class CL {
   public $a = 1;
   public $b;

   function __construct() {
       $this->b = "$this->a";
   }
}

$c = new CL;

echo $c->b; // Выведет: 1
```

Заметьте, что объявление переменной `$a` перенесено в класс. У вас нарушение [области видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) в коде.

[Подробнее о конструкторах и деструкторах](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 4):

Класс - это, так сказать, отдельный организм. Он никак не связан с внешнем миром. Не зря он отделяется скобками `{ }`, как бы ограничивая все, что внутри от того, что снаружи.

В нем могут быть свои переменные с именем `$a`, даже если вне есть с аналогичным именем.

Достать ту заветную переменную можно разве что в отдельном методе и с помощью `global` - это дает понять классу, что можно работать с этой глобальной переменной.

Пример:

```
$a = 1;
class CL {      
   public $b = 666;

   public function test() {
        global $a;
        return $a;
   }
}

$c = new CL();

echo $c->test();
```

В методе тест мы указываем на то, что хотим работать с переменной `$a`, которая вне класса.
Но так (использовать `global`) уже никто не делает и это неприемлемо.

В вашем случае, как следствие, переменная `$a` в своем внутреннем мире просто напросто не существует. Поэтому присвоение переменной `$b` значение несуществующей в классе переменной `$a` выдает ошибку.

Если же эта переменная должна использоваться в классе, тогда её необходимо также поместить внутрь класса:

```
class CL {
   public $a = 1;   
   public $b;

}
```

И в нем оперировать этими переменными так, как вы захотите.

Если же отвечать на вопрос: "Как вызвать $a, не выходя за пределы строки и не меняя структуру класса?", ответ - никак.

p.s. один момент. можно объявить `a` константой и тогда все получится

```
<?php 
class CL{
   const a = 1;
   public $b = self::a;

   public function test() {
    return $this->b;
   }
}

echo (new CL)->test();
?>
```

Только сами понимаете.. что константе уже нельзя будет ничего присвоить в дальнейшем. Поэтому на сколько это оправдано это ненужное извращение.....глупо.....но работает именно так, как вы хотите - без доп. изменений класса)